# gcc/clang optimization of little-endian load of uint16_t from uint8_t* array

Tags: c, gcc, clang, compiler-optimization

Given the below:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

uint16_t foo(uint8_t* x)
{
  uint16_t r = (x[1] << 8) | x[0];
  return r;
}

uint16_t bar(uint8_t* x)
{
  uint16_t r = ((uint16_t*) x)[0];
  return r;
}
```

On x86_64, both GCC and Clang produce code similar to:

```
foo:                                    # @foo
        .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:                                 # %entry
        movzbl  (%rdi), %ecx
        movzbl  1(%rdi), %eax
        shll    $8, %eax
        orl     %ecx, %eax
        movzwl  %ax, %eax
        ret

bar:                                    # @bar
        .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:                                 # %entry
        movzwl  (%rdi), %eax
        ret
```

Is there any reason why foo is not optimized to be equivalent to bar (i.e., doing a single 16-bit load)? Alignment of loads?

Comment: Shouldn't you typecast `x[1]` to a uint16_t before shifting? Otherwise it seems that you will get `x[1] << 8 == 0` since there are only 8 bits and you are shifting them all out.

Comment: @Matt `x[1]` is promoted to `int` in `x[1] << 8`.

Comment: @Matt: No, the "integer promotions" apply, and `x[1]` is promoted to `int` before the shift.

Answer (score 2):

I don't write compilers, but I can have good guess:

None of the standard optimization techniques that compilers use would affect the code in `foo` . To detect that it's equivalent to `bar` would require a specific optimization designed to spot this particular pattern, and output the 'improved' code instead.

So, why isn't there a specific optimization for this? Probably the usual reason:

> "Insufficient return on investment"

In other words, the time spent coding, debugging and maintaining the optimization - and the extra compile time spent checking every line of source for this pattern - would swamp any benefit gained from it.

And, of course you have `htons/ntohs` already. I'd just use those.

> Alignment of loads?

That's an interesting one and I had to look it up. If your incoming pointer 'x' was not word aligned, then `bar` would crash on many architectures, while `foo` should still work.

However x86 architecture allows misaligned loads, so both functions should work even for unaligned values of x.

Comment: I had some memory of seeing optimization like this happening before, which was why I was asking. Of course, it's entirely possible I'm just misremembering and indeed, neither gcc or Clang optimize this. :)

Comment: x86 *allows* misaligned loads, but they have a (relatively) large performance impact — so it'd be entirely possible the compiler was avoiding creating them.

Comment: @gsnedders, I agree that there's a performance impact - but 'bar' on misaligned data would probably outperform 'foo' regardless.

Comment: @Roddy: There are two sorts of systems that "allow" unaligned loads; some decompose the load into a sequence of operations which may or may not be perfectly optimal, but won't be far from it; others will trap to an OS routine which can observe what instruction attempted the unaligned load, "emulate" its behavior, and return to the underlying program.  When generating code for the former implementations, if one needs a single unaligned load, one should use one; for the latter implementations, one should always avoid them.  In either case...

Comment: ...if one may need a bunch of consecutive unaligned loads in speed-critical code, it may be best to hand-process various cases (e.g. load an odd byte plus eight aligned 32-bit words into registers, rotate the byte into the words stored in registers, and then store all eight aligned 32-bit registers).